# VxWorks issue Can't load boot file

Tags: vxworks

I have an industrial robot arm that has VxWorks running in the controller. I am very new to VxWorks. When I tried to use ftp, there was a password issue. After going through the vxworks boot procedure, I can no longer get the system to boot. I get the following screen through HyperTerminal.

```
    VxWorks System Boot


Copyright 1984-2002  Wind River Systems, Inc.





CPU: PC PENTIUM
Version: VxWorks5.5.1
BSP version: 1.2/2
Creation date: Nov  3 2006, 09:55:58




Press 's' to stop auto-boot...

auto-booting...


boot device          : ata

unit number          : 0

processor number     : 0

host name            : NITT

file name            : /ata0/vxWorks

inet on ethernet (e) : 192.168.0.253:1947

host inet (h)        : 192.168.0.255

user (u)             : me

ftp password (pw)    : pw

flags (f)            : 0x00

other (o)            : fei


Attaching to USB disk device...

USBLink, USB Stack Driver, ver 2.02 (build 31/01/2006), staubli rev 1.10

Copyright SoftConnex LLC, 1999. All rights reserved...

UHCI USB Controller initialized ...

Can't load boot file!!



I look at the terse help menue...

[VxWorks Boot]: ?


 ?                     - print this list

 @                     - boot (load and go)

 p                     - print boot params

 c                     - change boot params

 l                     - load boot file

 g adrs                - go to adrs

 d adrs[,n]            - display memory

 m adrs                - modify memory

 f adrs, nbytes, value - fill memory

 t adrs, adrs, nbytes  - copy memory

 e                     - print fatal exception

 v                     - print boot logo with version

 n netif               - print network interface device address

 $dev(0,procnum)host:/file h=# e=# b=# g=# u=usr [pw=passwd] f=#

                           tn=targetname s=script o=other

 boot device: ata=ctrl,drive           file name: /ata0/vxWorks

 boot device: usbstbl                      file name: /usbdsk0/vxWorks

 Boot flags:

   0x02  - load local system symbols

   0x04  - don't autoboot

   0x08  - quick autoboot (no countdown)

   0x20  - disable login security

   0x40  - use bootp to get boot parameters

   0x80  - use tftp to get boot image

   0x100 - use proxy arp

available boot devices:Enhanced Network Devices

 fei0 fei1 ata usbstbl

[VxWorks Boot]:
```

The system did previously boot without a PC.
Does anyone see any errors in the parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You have the system configured to load from the ata device. We can see from this line:

```
available boot devices:Enhanced Network Devices

 fei0 fei1 ata usbstbl
```

that the ata device does exist. So, the most likely explanation is that the file `/ata/vxworks` no longer exists. Perhaps it has been deleted, or maybe corrupted, or the disk has been formatted. You can check what is on disk using the ls command:

`ls /ata`

You may be able to recover using another boot method, eg configure to download the boot image via the network or, assuming that `usbstb1` is some form of removable storage, by copying a vxworks image onto the system that way.

Using a USB device, you can either modify the boot config to temporarily load the vxworks from the USB (you will need to modify boot device and file name settings), or use the bootloader shell commands to copy the boot file to the target.

**Copy file from USB**

Using a PC, copy the vxworks image to the USB device - it doesnt matter where, as long as you know where.

Insert the USB into your target.
using the shell commands, copy the file eg

`cp /usbdsk0/vxWorks /ata0/vxWorks`

Comment: Thank you very much mjs. However, I am not able to get out of the [VxWorks Boot] :  I think the ls command may be what got me in trouble. By default it tries to load a file named "s" , the file after "L". Is there a generic boot file for this type of system on the web I can try thorough the USB port?

Comment: No idea, we don't know what sort of system it is. It is very unlikely though, due to license issues. Surely you have the image somewhere, or can rebuild it?

Comment: It looks like I have the files. However, However, the instructions are poorly written. I have two folders: usr and sys. It looks like I am instructed to create a folder named "boot" and put the usr and sys folder inside of "boot" on a USB drive. Put the drive in a specified USB port and follow command prompts.  Does that look like normal protocol? Again, I want to thank you for your responses.

Comment: Updated answer. I don't think we can help any further though, as this is the specifics of your implementation, and as such is to localized for stack overflow.